# SQL CROSS JOIN with WHERE CLAUSE not returning anything

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am trying to get a result for the query:

```
SELECT product, exportcountry
FROM is_exported_to CROSS JOIN is_produced_in
WHERE product = cheese AND origin = 'France';
```

But I cannot seem to get any return.

The two tables were created as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE is_produced_in(
  cheese VARCHAR(32),
  origin VARCHAR(32)
  );

  INSERT INTO is_produced_in (cheese, origin)
  VALUES 
  ('Brie', 'France'),
  ('Chrur', 'Tibet'),
  ('Halloumi', 'Greece'),
  ('Orgu', 'Turkey'),
  ('Salers', 'France'),
  ('Serrano', 'Brazil')

CREATE TABLE is_exported_to(
  product VARCHAR(32),
  exportcountry VARCHAR(32)
);

INSERT INTO is_exported_to (product, exportcountry)
VALUES
  ('Brie', 'Greece'),
  ('Halloumi', 'Brazil'),
  ('Halloumi', 'France'),
  ('Halloumi', 'Tibet'),
  ('Orgu', 'France'),
  ('Orgu', 'Tibet'),
  ('Salers', 'Greece'),
  ('Serrano', 'Tibet'),
  ('Serrano', 'Turkey')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed ";" in your init scipt.

```
CREATE TABLE is_produced_in(
  cheese VARCHAR(32),
  origin VARCHAR(32)
  );

  INSERT INTO is_produced_in (cheese, origin)
  VALUES 
  ('Brie', 'France'),
  ('Chrur', 'Tibet'),
  ('Halloumi', 'Greece'),
  ('Orgu', 'Turkey'),
  ('Salers', 'France'),
  ('Serrano', 'Brazil');

CREATE TABLE is_exported_to(
  product VARCHAR(32),
  exportcountry VARCHAR(32)
);

INSERT INTO is_exported_to (product, exportcountry)
VALUES
  ('Brie', 'Greece'),
  ('Halloumi', 'Brazil'),
  ('Halloumi', 'France'),
  ('Halloumi', 'Tibet'),
  ('Orgu', 'France'),
  ('Orgu', 'Tibet'),
  ('Salers', 'Greece'),
  ('Serrano', 'Tibet'),
  ('Serrano', 'Turkey');
```

Query sql can be:

```
SELECT product, exportcountry
FROM is_exported_to CROSS JOIN is_produced_in
ON product = cheese AND origin = 'France';
```

Use "ON" instead of "WHERE"

see: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3jC8PGeZZEuty3XVq8gdzz/2

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to specify join condition in cross join.
You can use the following query:

```
SELECT * from is_exported_to 
CROSS JOIN is_produced_in 
WHERE origin='France'
```

Comment: Thank you for the input, hopefully I'll get more used to alternative methods for different situations. It's much appreciated, truely.